# Do razor blades work as solar panels?

Tags: solar-cell, power-generation

I want to know if there is any scientific background to the use of razor blades as solar panels. Would someone please explain how this composition of blades will generate electricity when put in sunlight (if it in fact will).

The image is taken from [this video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=ayV0ZzNvt1U)

[image]

Comment: They probably don't.  There's a lot of people out there who make videos of things that don't work.  The videos are nothing more than click bait so that the video creator earns advertising money for each view of the video.  Your "razor blade solar cells" looks very much like such a fake video.

Comment: A link to the video would be a good start.  If there's a circuit diagram, it would be good to make a screen shot of it and include it in the question.

Comment: The guy probably has a battery up his sleeve.

Comment: The battery is behind the razor blades.

Comment: The question should be "how to fake razor solar panels for gullible people on YouTube" :) It would even be slightly on-topic, since it involves electrical engineering.

Comment: It's complete rubbish! Even if the blades did somehow generate electricity when exposed to sunlight (which they don't) there is only one connection to each blade so there is no circuit. The blades are solid metal, a good conductor, so every part will be at essentially the same potential and again there is no potential difference that could be tapped off.

Comment: THE QUESTION DOES NOT DESERVE THE DOWNVOTES - he yelled :-). It's not the fault of the OP that he has met a shyster. The question and answers are informative for others whp may see similar.

Comment: I’m closing to re-open to clear close-votes. The fact this does not work is not the OP's fault. The question meets the primary site criteria.

Comment: I don't think this belongs here though, maybe at https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/. Don't search for wisdom at Youtube or at the end of a bottle.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's really not our job to debunk YouTube videos that are so clearly fake. (though, just as Russel, I do think there could have been a good question behind this, if OP took the time to research properly and ask a question not based on the questionable assumption that this video had any factual background)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The aspect under which it would be on-topic would be that it's about the theory behind electronics. But if it is, it would be far too broad. Like we would close a question that was "why does the bulb light up when I close the switch in a battery + -switch- -lamp- battery - circuit".

Comment: @RussellMcMahon also, I must say, though I'm usually very much on board with moderation here, "I'm closing and reopening this question to clear votes" seems to me really really not the way to deal with moderation on here. I understand mods should have the last word, but to preempt that a question gets closed by erasing votes is imho clearly exceeding the moderation competences as last resort when community self-moderation fails. I don't know whether you can, but I'd ask you to restore the previously given close votes.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  If a question is closed and then edited adequately it can be reopened. The decision whether the reopening is justified by the edit is vested in the (mere mortal) moderators. I edited the question prior to close/opening it.  Somebody else could have done some editing. I try to keep editing light enough to not change the gist of the question. I added the video link (provided by someone else). I changed the subject line and made the question more a question. The excellent answer by JRE has 9 upvotes (at the time I write this). The question meets the site prime directive stated ...

Comment: ... long ago by one of the original owners and generally lost sight of. "The aim of the site is to generate question and answer sets  that last and which attract search engine traffic to the site. All the rest is built on this (seldom seen) foundation. [Add :-) if desired].  | The OP came here having seen an apparent demo of a genuine device. The video said that it stopped working after a while - it adds credence to the scam. (The battery went flat :-( ). If he'd gone looking for confirmation on the internet it would be good if he could find a quality response. They can be few and far between.

Comment: Asking on Googlabet : can you make a solar panel using razor blades -> all the hits bar one mentioning razor blades on the first page lead to fake videos. And [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.nz/pin/666955026063620251/) has its share along with the free energy scams. | BUT also on the first page, already, was a link to this answer. || I am unable to restore the downvotes. ||

Comment: re " ... erasing votes is imho clearly exceeding the moderation competences ... " -> Moot. As above, I think not if due care is taken, as described above.  I've thought for a while about asking a meta question re this (occasional) practice of mine. Others are welcome to do so. |  I note that moderators are able to close a question with a single click. And to reopen a closed one. Closed questions have the close-votes of N members already. With editing by moderator or other this is no different.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I really appreciate you answering this! (the google result will be very different for different users. Once a user has been clicking on a few fake energy videos, it'll be hard to bring this up to the result lists anyway, so let's keep SEO out of this discussion, I think!) See, the thing is that your edit certainly improved the question, it added clarity and actually spelt out what OP was wondering about, and as that would be necessary to make it a good question. Was it sufficient to make it a technical question with an engineering background and sufficient own research?

Comment: the two of us argue for different things – and mere mortals that we are, that's really really OK.

Comment: Now, that's where SO's vote system comes in: solving these kinds of disputes in an uncomplicated, democratic manner :) I'm not saying you should never do what you did here (greatly improve a question and then undo the damage that the worse original question caused), I'm saying that this question here is still of such questionable focus (not your fault! Can't be fixed by content-preserving edits) that maybe undoing the damage completely was a bit of a strong measure.

Answer (score 9):

Razor blades don't work as solar panels.

The video is a fake.

If you watch it, you'll see that the blades don't form any part of a closed circuit.

The back panel is just cardboard:

[image]

The razor blades are merely glued on:

[image]

The metal strips are aluminum foil - you can't solder connections to it with normal solder.  The strips are glued in place as well.

The circled blobs are the wires going out the back of the panel to connect a real battery hidden behind the panel:

[image]

The blobs aren't connected to the aluminum foil.  They just sit on it, stuck to the tips of wires coming through from the back.

The wire clips are soldered directly to the wires from behind the panel.  Notice how he's soldering the clip wires to the blobs rather than to the metal strips.  He can't solder to the strips because the strips are aluminum.

[image]

The blades only lie on the aluminum strips.  They will not have a good connection to the strips at all.

Here you can clearly see that the blades aren't really well connected to the strips:

[image]

The halves are identical.  If they did by some weird quirk actually respond to light, both halves would be at the same potential - no current would flow.  There would be no positive or negative.

It's a fake.  A hoax made to collect clicks so that the hoaxter earns advertising money for each video view.

It doesn't work.  It can't work.

Comment: It's worth noting that you could solder directly to aluminum. It takes care but it does work. I've done that many times to get grounding wires to connect to bent sheet metal aluminum project boxes. As shown in the video, even that bit didn't work :/

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica:  If you've managed to solder to aluminum with regular solder then you are a far more patient person than I am.

Comment: @JRE I've managed it once. Took ages. Not doing it again!

Comment: TopTip - don't solder to things connected to superglue, at least not in a confined space. It heats up and releases some noxious gases, much worse than what comes off at room temperature when curing normally.